# Is it possible to make an Explicit union containing an overlapping byte[] in C#?

Tags: c#, union

I'm trying to make this work, but I get this error..

*because it contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.*

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct ListEntry {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=17)]
        public byte[] raw;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
        public byte version;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(1)]
        public UInt16 magic;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(3)]
        public UInt32 start_time;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(7)]
        public UInt16 run_id;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(9)]
        public UInt16 channels;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(11)]
        public UInt16 sampling_rate;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(13)]
        public UInt32 start_sector;
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to use `fixed`? ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya(v=vs.80).aspx )

Comment: My personal feeling here is to just go `unsafe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps as a fixed size buffer?

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
public fixed byte raw[17];
```

Note you'll need to treat that as a `byte*` in code, for example:

```
byte* ptr = x.raw;
// now copy / inspect / whatever from ptr
```

Comment: I should add, though, that it might be easier to simply use a pointer coercion and write to a ***separate*** `byte*` as though it were a `ListEntry*`

Comment: The use of both fixed and unsafe are required.  Works Great.  Much better than all the marshal copy of data from this to that..

Comment: @Marc I want to be able to create an array of these objects and to copy data to them like http://pastebin.com/aFiYu2M0 but I get "You cannot use fixed size buffers contained in unfixed expressions".  How to get around?